# To prove for multichoose $\big(\!{{a+b}\choose k}\!\big)= \sum_{j=0}^k \big(\!{a\choose j}\!\big) \cdot \big(\!{b\choose {k-j}}\!\big)$

Tags: binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

$$\left(\!\!{{a+b}\choose k}\!\!\right)= \sum_{j=0}^k \left(\!\!{a\choose j}\!\!\right) \cdot \left(\!\!{b\choose {k-j}}\!\!\right)$$

I am quite confused about the case of multichoose. I was able to prove this equation if only "n choose k" form was used as both sides would be the k-th coefficients of $(1+x)^{a+b}$.

Any help to understand this would be very appreciated.

Comment: The first term in the sum should be ${a\choose j}$ not ${a\choose k}$ - applies to both title and body.

Comment: But I am not clear what your question is anyway. One way of proving the identity (when corrected) is to use the combinatorial interpretation of ${m\choose n}$ as "the number of ways of choosing a subset of $n$ items from a set of $m$ distinct items" Presumably you are interested in the case where the items are not all distinct. But the answer then depends on how many of each type there are. So do you want the multinomial coefficient?

Comment: @almagest i have edited out the mistake, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Not yet in the title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This binomial identity is an  instance  of  the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.

> We  start  with  the right-hand side. We  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^k\left(\!\!\binom{a}{j}\!\!\right)\!\!\left(\!\!\binom{b}{k-j}\!\!\right)}
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{a+j-1}{j}\binom{b+k-j-1}{k-j}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{-a}{j}(-1)^j\binom{-b}{k-j}(-1)^{k-j}\tag{2}\\
> &=(-1)^k\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{-a}{j}\binom{-b}{k-j}\\
> &=(-1)^k\binom{-a-b}{k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{a+b+k-1}{k}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\!\!\binom{a+b}{k}\!\!\right)}
> \end{align*}
>   and  the   claim  follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the definition of the *[multiset coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets)*.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3)  we apply  the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu%E2%80%93Vandermonde_identity)*.

**Note:** We  see from (2)  and  (3) the identity is  in  terms of  generating functions with  $[z^k]$  denoting the coefficient of $z^k$ in the series:
\begin{align*}
[z^{k}](1-z)^{-a-b}=[z^k](1-z)^{-a}(1-z)^{-b}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ways to choose any $k$ objects from two piles (of size $a$ and $b$).

One way is to simply combine the piles and choose them (the ways to do this is $\binom{a+b}k$, a.k.a. the LHS).

Another way is to first choose some, say, $j$ objects from pile $a$ (can be done in $\binom aj$ ways) and then choose the remaining $k-j$ objects from pile $b$ (can be done in $\binom b{k-j}$ ways, so this operation may be done in $\binom aj \binom b{k-j}$ ways). Adding all the cases for the different $j$s we get $\sum_{j=0}^k \binom aj \binom b{k-j}$. From the equivalence of these processes we get the result.

Comment: but isn't that simply "a+b choose k" "a choose j" and "b choose k-j" that is being explained? What would happen if choose was replaced by multichoose?

Comment: unfortunately, that is where i'm getting confused.

Comment: maybe try the above line of reasoning except with placing objects in $a+b$ boxes.